# replace image src many times gets slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I wanted to stresstest and preload our imageserver. I want to see all images...

The url is //media.our.dom/{id}/size

I set up 400 dummy thumbnails

```php
<?php 
for ($n=0;$n<400;$n++) {
    printf("<img src='//media.our.dom/0/size' id='img_%d'>",$n);
}
?>
```

Then I load one image, as soon as it's finished, load the next one, etc.

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
      loadimg(1000);
})
function loadimg(n) {
i = n % 400;
$("#img_" + i).attr('src', '//media.our.dom/' + n + '/thumb').load(function() {
   if (n < 50000) loadimg(n + 1)
  })
}
```

So I have 400 images, and each one gets replaced, one by one, it looks like a cursor is going from left to right, top to bottom, and then back to top left.

It works fine in the beginning, starts with about 10 images/sec, but it slows down, after 1000 images it takes 4 sec/image, and some time later chrome crashes.

I see two reasons why it could fail:

1. data of the replaced images does not get released.
2. the loadimg() calls itself recursively, causing memory leak

So if (1), can I release the data

if (2) how can I do it non-recursively?

I wouldn't mind having more threads loading images at the same time, e.g. one thread taking even images, one odd, or even better 10/20 images loaded at the same time, to stress the imageserver.

Comment: `the loadimg() calls itself recursively, causing memory leak` Once images are cached, the `load` event is fired instantly, calling same function again and again. This could be the reason of browser freezing. Have you try setting a timestamp to image url? `$("#img_" + i).attr('src', '//media.our.dom/' + n + '/thumb?' + $.now())`. And FYI, `$("document")` should be `$(document).`

Comment: It is not the same image, i=n mod 400.
So first time <img id='img_1'> gets image1,jpg, next time image401.jpg, then image801,jpg

Comment: Oh sorry, you are using `n` in url, not `i`, my bad!