# Is n++/n-- atomic, (Running same function multiple times triggered by setinterval)

Tags: javascript, jquery

TL;DR;

```
setInterval(doit,10);
function doit(if(q<10){q++;do_something().onFinished(q--)})
```

have inconsistent q if run many times simultaneously.

---

I want to load thousands of images (thumbnails) as fast as possible.

I've tried with jQuery `.load`, to load the next image when one image was loaded, but it slowed to a crawl and crashed the browser.

[replace image src many times gets slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968152/replace-image-src-many-times-gets-slow)

My current attempt is as follows:

- I have preloaded 400 images with id img_0 to img_399
- I want to load 30 images at a time

-

```
var q = 0    //queue length
var n = 0    //Image number

$("document").ready(function() {
    cnt=setInterval(loadimg,10); // every 10ms
})

function loadimg() {
if (q < 30) { // if less than 30 images being loaded
    m=++n;    
    q++; // increase queue length
    i = m % 400;
    $("#cnt").html(m)
    $("#queue").html(q)
    $("#img_" + i).attr('src', '//media.paradiss.dk/' + m + '').load(function() {
        q-- //decrease queue length when done.
    })
    } else {
       console.log("busy q:"+q);
    }
}
```

My idea is this:

The setInterval fires loadimg every 10ms.
If the queue length (q) is less than 30, loadimg increments the queue length counter, loads the image, and when the image is loaded, the queue length is decremented.

But while q never gets above the specified 30, suddenly it drops below 0. If not restricted, it can go to minus many thousands.

is q++ and q-- not atomic?

Comment: No ++ is not atomic. In fact I can't think of a language off hand where it is.

Comment: It's actually a slightly invalid question as javascript does not allow multi-threading. Using setInterval (or similar) does not create threads but rather creates asynchronous execution.  You get inconsistent behavior due to the asynchronous behavior and slight variations in calculation time, especially since the timeout is only 10ms.  If you have a relatively large timeout with a relatively small calculation then you would *probably* be consistent but even then, don't bet on it.

Comment: OK, any ideas to do what I want?

Comment: Set up a recursive loop to be called in the 'complete' of the jquery load.  You can put a counter in there or use some other way of keeping track of whether or not it is done with all of the images.

Comment: Tried that. See link in my question. Didn't work.

Comment: Try a recursive loop on a setTimeout instead of the .load.  This is common for things like loading bars, it increments every 100ms (or similar).

Comment: Please supply example, and look at my failed attempt in the link in my question.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with atomicy of operations. In fact, JS does never execute in parallel, there are no data races. All asynchronous events are processed sequentially in a queue, where every call is run-to-completion.

> But `q` suddenly it drops below 0. If not restricted, it can go to minus many thousands.

That is when you are loading more than 400 images. You are attaching a new `load` callback every time you load a new src, but you never remove them. After 400 loaded images, the `img` elements will have multiple event handlers attached, decreasing `q` multiple times when an image loads.